# On the syntax of 'Cogitate quantis laboribus fundatum imperium (...) una nox paene delerit' (Cic. Cat. 4, 19)

Tags: syntax, participle, word-order, subordinate-clause, cicero

Picking up the thread of analyzing beautiful structures involving participles in Cicero's works (e.g. see this [link](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/on-the-syntax-of-some-datives-in-a-beautiful-ciceronian-structure)), I'd like to raise a question about the syntax of the following complex sentence. To put it in the words of [Wightman and Knapp (1934: 206)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4339407?seq=1): "here is a sentence to diagram!".

> Cogitate, *quantis laboribus* **fundatum** imperium, *quanta virtute* **stabilitam** libertatem, *quanta deorum benignitate* **auctas exaggeratas**que fortunas una nox paene delerit (Cic. *Cat*. 4, 19).

Transl. by C.D. Yonge (1856): ‘Think with what great labour this our dominion was founded, by what virtue this our liberty was established, by what kind favour of the gods our fortunes were aggrandized and ennobled, and how nearly one night destroyed them all’.

In this [link](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0050%3Atext%3DCatil.%3Aspeech%3D4%3Achapter%3D9) from Perseus the following interesting note by Greenough & Kittredge can also be found: "*quantis . . . delerit*: this clause will be best turned into English by translating the participles *fundatum*, etc., as verbs, and *delerit* as a relative clause, 'with how great toil this empire was established, which one night', etc. In Latin the question is contained in the interrogative modifiers of *imperium* and not in the main clause". Similarly, in this [link](https://pdfhost.io/v/toLhF576Jt_Speeches_against_Catilina.pdf) the commentator says on page 81: "A short form of expression combining two really distinct indirect questions, (1) *cogitate quantis laboribus imperium fundatum  sit*  and  (2) *cogitate  ut  una  nox  paene  (imperium)  delerit*'.  In English, 'Think by what toil was the empire established, which one night nearly destroyed'."

These English translations can be said to be very good but it is important to realize that they involve a syntax that is different from what we really find in Latin: i.e., in the Latin complex sentence above the exclamative (cf. "interrogative" in Greenough & Kittredge's note above) constituents (*quantis laboribus*, *quanta virtute*, and *quanta deorum benignitate*) modify participles (*fundatum*, *stabilitam*, and *auctas exaggeratasque*), which in turn depend on the nominal heads of the direct objects (*imperium*, *libertatem*, and *fortunas*) of the subordinate verb *dele(ve)rit*. **For some reason strange to me** the exclamative nature of the adjunct participle construction (e.g. *quantis laboribus fundatum*) appears to "percolate up" to the subordinate clause of the verb *dele(ve)rit*. Could anyone shed light on what is going on here? I was wondering whether the existence of these examples can be related to the claim that Latin is a ["discourse-configurational language"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9548/what-is-the-term-for-extremely-loose-latin-word-order) (NB: "discourse-configurational languages" are those ones where either or both of the discourse-semantic functions "topic" and "focus" are linked to particular structural positions. For relevant discussion of the important claim that Latin is a "discourse-configurational language", see the following references: Devine, Andrew M. & Laurence D. Stephens (2006). *Latin Word Order. Structured Meaning and Information*. New York: Oxford University Press // Devine, Andrew M. & Laurence D. Stephens (2019). *Pragmatics for Latin. From Syntax to Information Structure*. New York: Oxford University Press).

That could explain why it is nearly impossible to provide a good direct translation of the Latin example above into English and other 'plainly configurational' [languages I know of](https://www.facebook.com/AEGERIVSLICIVSCONTINVVS/photos/a.738452429530913/2589978821044922/?type=3) (e.g., cf. the relative-clause strategy put foward by Greenough & Kittredge in their note above with the coordination strategy used by Yonge in his English translation above: '*and how* nearly one night destroyed them all’).

Comment: What rules out a literal translation in English, specifically, is the Ross "island constraint" on extraction from wh-questions. Latin seems to lack that particular constraint. I'm not sure this has anything to do with discourse configurationality, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: That said it's not quite clear to me what your question is. Are you asking why *delerit* is subjunctive? That seems to be dictated by the normal rules of indirect questions.

Comment: @TKR Thanks for your interesting comment! For other cases (the ones related to hyperbaton) where Latin disobeys syntactic island constraints, see http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/28/paper2455.pdf and https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/phonology/article/phonological-constituents-and-their-movement-in-latin/13908F602D093BDD18120275963B4EC0

Comment: @TKR No, I'm not asking why _delerit_ is subjunctive. I'm asking why examples like the one in the title are possible in Latin but not in English, Spanish, etc. In my post above I tentatively point out that this typological difference could have to do with the (non)-configurationality issue but I'm not so sure. Hence the present question.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm familiar with that paper in its 2010 *Language* version, which makes similar points but is IIRC confined to Greek. Cf. also violation of the adjunct island constraint as in e.g. τί παθὼν τοῦτο ἐποίησας; and Latin equivalents. It would be interesting to see an overall study of syntactic islands in Latin and/or Greek -- I don't know if this has been done.

Comment: @TKR Yes, you recall it correctly:  http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/~chrisg/PhMovement_files/Agbayani%26GolstonLanguage.pdf  Yes, I fully agree with you. I don't know if such an overall study exists.

Comment: Let me prime the pump a little by asking: "A book read by how many people do I need to become a famous author?" Does that sound so wrong? If we can say that, we should also be able to say: "Consider an empire by how much labour built, a freedom by how much courage established, fortunes by what great benevolence of the gods increased and raised up a single night almost annihilated." Is this really impossible?

Comment: @Mitomino: What about the ablative-absolute treatment? Giving: "quantis laboribus" = "with/ by the quantity having-been-laboured (with/ by the volume of work that was done); "quanta virtute" = "with/ by the quantity (of presumably will-power) given-up to virtue [It cannot be rendered as: having-been-"virtued"]; "quanta deorum benignitate" = "with/ by the quantity having been favoured [with/ by the volume of good-will of the gods]". The other grammatical points (all the accusatives dictated by imperative, "cogitate"; perfect subjunctive, "delerit" for the indirect questions [Cerberus]

Comment: @Mitomino: have been explained. Cerberus, in an excellent answer, is entirely correct; here, there is a wide gulf of incompatibility between the Latin & the English--evidenced by my own attempts to bend the ablative-absolute (literal) translations to fit the understood-English.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Your English translation is "understandable" but it is not natural at all (NB: grammaticality is not a matter of "understandability"). Note also that the subordinate clause selected by "consider" lacks the exclamative force of the Latin example. Here the main predicate _cogitate_ selects an exclamative clause as its argument. In English this exclamative force is naturally obtained by putting "how" or the ablative WH-constituent just after the main verb _cogitate_. Same in the languages I know of. Perhaps in the German translations at your disposal it's also the same.

Comment: @tony I do not see any Ablative Absolute in the Latin example above. So I'm afraid we understand this typical construction of Latin syntax differently. The three ablative constituents are modifiers of the participles (e.g. _quantis laboribus_ 'with what great labour(s)' is just a modifier of the participle _fundatum_. Your gloss of _quantis laboribus_  as 'with/ by the quantity having-been-laboured' sounds very unnatural to me and in fact is not correct).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summary: the reason why this sentence seems unusual after translation is only because of the limits of English syntax, not because anything odd in the Latin.

> A short form of expression combining two really distinct indirect questions

I do not understand why the commentator read the sentence that way. It is theoretically possible to read the first interrogative clause as subordinate to *cogitate* directly:

> cogitate quantis laboribus fundatum imperium [sit]

Elliptic *sit* is not unreasonable in isolation, and *fundatum imperium* could be nominative. However, this is not possible with the other interrogative clauses, because it says *quanta virtute stabilit**am** liberta**tem***, not **quanta virtute stabilit**a** libert**as** [sit]*. The accusative makes that *sit* impossible, so *libertatem* and *fortunas* must be objects to something; and *delerit* is the only candidate:

> Cogitate...quanta virtute stabilitam libertatem...una nox delerit

This makes perfect sense in Latin, but it cannot be translated literally, because this type of layered nesting is incompatible with English syntax ("think the-freedom-stabilised-by-how-much-virtue one night destroyed": this is ugly). The same applies to the third interrogative clause.

So, if we follow this commentator, we have three interrogative clauses with some ellipsis, supplied as follows:

> cogitate quantis laboribus fundatum imperium [sit]
> [cogitate] quanta virtute stabilitam libertatem [una nox paene delerit]
> [cogitate] quanta deorum benignitate auctas exaggeratasque fortunas una nox paene delerit

But I think the lectio brevis makes much more sense—and is to be preferred stylistically—, i.e. a normal [tricolon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trikolon) (three parallel constructions):

> cogitate quantis laboribus fundatum imperium [una nox paene delerit]
> [cogitate] quanta virtute stabilitam libertatem [una nox paene delerit]
> [cogitate] quanta deorum benignitate auctas exaggeratasque fortunas una nox paene delerit

So I think this is the only reasonable reading of the sentence. It must be translated somewhat liberally, though; so I understand why those translations 'flattened' the syntax, turning it into four parallel interrogative clauses instead, adding the word *how* to introduce the final clause:

> think with what great labour this our dominion was founded,
> [think] by what virtue this our liberty was established,
> [think] by what kind favour of the gods our fortunes were aggrandized and ennobled,
> and [think] how nearly one night destroyed them all

The translation using *which* to introduce the fourth clause after flattening would seem an equally good option.

---

In conclusion, there is nothing odd about the Latin; it is just English which is incapable of rendering the same construction.

---

[Edit:] Let me illustrate the problem in English.

> Think how much power one night destroyed.

This is possible. The interrogative phrase *how much* must come at the beginning of the interrogative clause: this is a strict requirement of English in the present context.

> Think how strong an empire one night destroyed.

This is still possible, because *how strong* is at the beginning of the interrogative clause, and the adjectival phrase *how strong* can come before its head, the noun *an empire*. The latter is possible, because a plain adjective like *strong* can come before its noun.

> Think how well established an empire one night destroyed.

The participial phrase *how well established* can again go before its head noun, so still no problem.

> *Think by how much toil established an empire one night destroyed.

Suddenly, we lose grammaticality. The iron law of interrogative and relative pronouns requires that *by how much* should come at the beginning; however, the participial phrase is now such that it cannot be before the noun any more: **by how much toil established an empire* is not proper English. The reason is probably that it becomes somewhat ambiguous or somewhat [garden-path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) like: you could naïvely read *established* as a simple past now, a finite verb; or as a praeposited participial phrase modifying the verb ("by how much toil established did one night do something"); by the end, you'd know this was not right, and you'd arrive at the right reading: but that is too much work, it requires too much of the reader.

> ?An empire by so much toil established one night destroyed.

This is somewhat awkward, but perhaps still grammatical: with a moderate amount of puzzling or rereading, this sentence is readable. What I did was move the participial phrase to the right of its head noun. But I removed *how*. If we want to add *how* back in, we get this:

> *Think an empire by how much toil established one night destroyed.

This is an alternative attempt at constructing the sentence: instead of moving the phrase *by how toil established* to an unnatural position to the left of its head, we keep it at the right. But now the problem is that *by how much*, the interrogative phrase, is no longer at the beginning of the interrogative clause. This is unacceptable in English, probably also because of a garden-path like issue: at a glance, you'd begin reading the sentence thinking *an empire* was some sort of object to *think*, which is wrong. That is why the interrogative phrase really must go at the beginning of an interrogative clause.

So we have two rules here which conflict:

- an interrogative phrase must come at the beginning of its interrogative clause
- a participial phrase of great complexity must come after its head noun

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! I'm afraid that you misinterpreted the commentator's point above ("A short form of expression combining two really distinct indirect questions"). What (I understand) is meant by this commentator is that the Latin example involves a periphrastic combination of the following triplet in (1) _cogitate quantis laboribus imperium fundatum sit_; _cogitate quanta virtute libertas stabilita sit_; _cogitate quanta deorum benignitate fortunae auctae exaggerataeque sint_ and (2) _cogitate ut una nox paene {imperium/libertatem/fortunas} delerit_.

Comment: @Mitomino: Okay, a "periphrastic combination": what does that really mean? And why would such a reading be needed or desirable over the lectio simplex? I couldn't easily find the quotation in the linked document. P.S. I've added an explanation of why English does not allow a literal translation.

Comment: Here _periphrastic_ means 'wordy', 'roundabout', the result of a paraphrase (in Spanish we say "rodeo"). BTW, let me say that I fully agree with your conclusion: "there is nothing odd about Latin; it is just English which is incapable of rendering the same construction". Or, to put it in the neutral typological words of my post, Latin belongs to a type of languages that allow this type of constructions, whereas English belongs to a different type that doesn't allow it. As noted above, I wonder if this difference could (?) have to do with the so-called "(non)configurationality" of languages.

Comment: When you say "I do not understand why the commentator read the sentence that way", please note that what (I understand) he was trying to do was just to clarify the **content** of the complex Latin sentence to a reader of English. What is said by him is not necessarily incompatible with what you call the lectio brevis. In any case, as emphasized in your interesting edit (+1!), the question above is not so about the real ellipses involved in the tricolon (a debatable issue, indeed) but rather about why the example in the title of the post (without a tricolon) is ok in Latin but not in English.

Comment: @Mitomino: Right, the ellipsis I supplied was just a possible example. In your version here, though, we still do not have three independent sentences; if we wanted to expand into independent sentences, those interrogatives would still need to depend on something (we'd need to supply three somethings). But I agree it is not really important to the central thought of your question. (I usually see filling in ellipsis as a mere illustration of structure, rather than as the discovery of "real", specific words that should somehow exist invisibly.

Comment: @Mitomino About the underlying reason why Latin can do this but English cannot: a generic reason is that translating a construction from one language into another always 'favours' the original language: after all, the construction was naturally formed in this language. But I also think it may be because, to express syntax, English depends on word order very much, whereas Latin has more morphology which it uses for the same purpose, allowing for more flexibility in word order; this flexibility might make such nesting easier.

Comment: Notice that your Italian translation on Facebook also flattens the syntax: could that be because Italian, too, has more limited morphology than does Latin? Do you think a literal translation would be possible in Italian?

Comment: When I said that "the real ellipses involved in the tricolon is a debatable issue", I mean that this issue is not always obvious. For example, it seems clear that the tricolon above does not involve three instantiations of the main verb _cogitate_ but only one (after reading one of your last comments, I see we can agree on this point). This option discarded, two possibilities remain: (1) to the extent that the juxtaposition/coordination is that of three Nominal Phrases, _una nox paene delerit_ is **not** elliptical (let’s call it the what-you-see-is-what-you-get proposal) & ...

Comment: ...& (2) to the extent that the juxtaposition/coordination is that of three subordinate clauses, _una nox paene delerit_ is syntactically instantiated three times: i.e. to the extent that three landing sites for so-called "WH"-exclamative/interrogative elements (_quantis/quanta_ + abl. NP) are needed in subordination clauses, these elements must move up to the initial position of the subordinate clause of _delerit_ (here we can assume there can be only one WH-element per clause: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement).

Comment: The Italian translation in the Facebook link is not mine. As for your question “Do you think a literal translation would be possible in Italian?", no, I don’t think so (NB: I read & speak Italian but I’m not a native speaker of this language).

Answer (score 2):

There is little to add to the wonderful answer by @Cerberus, but I though it might be useful to add another possible way of translating this sentence into English by rendering the occurrences of *quantus* as being akin to rhetorical questions by "such":

*Ponder, how one night nearly destroyed this empire founded by such efforts, our liberty established by such virtues, our fortunes aggrandized and ennobled by such kind favour of the gods.*

or to preserve the logical order, by rendering the sentence in the passive voice:

*Ponder, how this empire founded by such efforts, our liberty established by such virtues, our fortunes aggrandized and ennobled by such kind favour of the gods were nearly destroyed in one night.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not a native speaker of English but your translations sound very natural to me.